# reference in r with logical vector of different length

Tags: r

The general scheme is a new diet was established and required to be administered with 7 grams of rodent meal everyday. I want to create a for loop that will take a vector containing the weight of diet that is given as c(3,6,8,5,11,4,5). And then I want to print out the message if the food is "more", "equal" or "less" than the reference intake. Then, I want to save logical constant TRUE to a logical vector named diet.suffice if the food is no less then the reference intake, else FALSE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `sign` to get the location relative to `ref`erence.

```
(r <- sign(x-ref))
# [1] -1 -1  1 -1  1 -1 -1  0
```

Adding `+2` we can use `switch`.

```
sapply(r + 2, function(x) switch(x, "less", "equal", "more"))
# [1] "less"  "less"  "more"  "less"  "more"  "less"  "less"  "equal"
```

Check if minimum intake holds.

```
(diet.suffice <- r > -1)
# [1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

---

*Data:*

```
ref <- 7
x <- c(3, 6, 8, 5, 11, 4, 5, 7)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! this time I was able to upvote and accept your answer, now I have to ability to do so. But why did you assign -1,0,1 in the first place?

Comment: @user432797 `switch` selects `1="less", 2="equal", 3="more"`, and `c(-1,0,1)+2` is `c(1, 2, 3)`. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1):

The problem can be vectorized, but assuming we need a `for` loop.  Initialize a logical vector (only `FALSE` values) to store the output (`diet.suffice`).  Loop over the sequence of values, `print` the different labels based on the comparison of that value with the reference value (using `if/else`)

```
diet.suffice <- logical(length(v1))
 
ref <- 4
for(i in seq_along(v1)) {
  if(v1[i] < ref) {
     print("less")   
    }  else if(v1[i] > ref) {
     print("more")
     diet.suffice[i] <- TRUE
     } else {
     print("equal")
    }
     
 
 }
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c(3,6,8,5,11,4,5)
```